# Magento: Layered Navigation by Price in Main Navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have a category called "Price" in my main navigation which has every product in the system assigned to it. The main point of the category is when you view it you can use the price filter on the layered navigation to filter any product on the site by price.

What I would like to do is output the price filter as a sub menu on the main navigation so a user could see a drop down of the different price bands and press one and be taken to the category with the filter already set.

I had a plan to edit this function Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation::_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml() and output this function Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract::getItems() if the category was called "Price" but I cant see a way to get the filters to out put from the category i pass it.

Has anyone done something like this before that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

if i was you i'd be tempted to change the plan a bit.

magento menus can be avoided. you can create you category and render a custom block for a price based filter.

if you extend Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price you can set your category and get most of the info.

probably the best thing might actually just be to build a little slider. it only has to go from the most expensive to cheapest price, or zero and then load the category list with price apllied.